# $1$st Order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was solving 1st order PDE which was 
\begin{equation}
(x^2-y^2-z^2)p+2xyq=2xz. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
I had tried to solve this. Please tell me whether it is correct or not.

$$\frac{dx}{x^2-y^2-z^2}=\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{dz}{2xz} \tag{2}$$
Grouping the 2nd and third we will get $$ \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z} $$ 
$$ \implies ln\ \frac{y}{z}=ln\ (c_1) \qquad (\text{consider}\ y,z>0)$$
So, I got the first integral surface $u=\frac{y}{z}=c_1$

Now, for getting the 2nd integral

$$ \frac{xdx}{x(x^2-y^2-z^2)}=\frac{ydy}{2xy^2}=\frac{zdz}{2xz^2} $$
Now add these three ratios, we will get 
$$ \frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \tag {3}  $$ Now group the third of (2) with the $(3)$ we will get 
\begin{eqnarray}
& & \frac{xdx+ydy+zdz}{x(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=\frac{dz}{2xz}\\
& \implies & \frac{2xdx+2ydy+2zdz}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=\frac{dz}{z}\\
& \implies & \log((x^2+y^2+z^2)=\log(zc_2)\\
& \implies & \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{z}=c_2\\
\end{eqnarray}
Hence, the 2nd integral surface is $ v=\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{z}=c_2. $ And, the complete solution will be $$ f\Big(\frac{y}{z},\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{z}\Big)=0 $$